# Cant find navigation controller to navigate another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a custom `UIPageViewController` which contain 5 `UIViewControllers`, now I would like to navigate from one of those 5 `UIViewController`, But I can't because in those `UIViewControllers` have no `UINavigationController`. Can anyone suggest me , how I can navigate from one those   5 `UIViewControllers` to other `UIViewController`?

Comment: you can navigate from one controller to other in this way :-
[self presentModalViewController:temp animated:YES];

Comment: I think you need to follow "http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?tag=ios-add-a-navigation-controller-programmatically" tutorial. You need to create the navigation bar Either through `Embed -> Navigation Controller` set it as initial view controller. Or follow the tutorial to manually create navigation bar

Comment: use the pageviewcontroller navigation and u can push the viewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your - `[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` 
might look like this (after checking your skipping condition of course):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAuth"]; //if you assigned this ID is storyboard
UIViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];  //if you assigned this ID is storyboard
UIViewController *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
NSArray *controllers = @[vc1, vc2, vc3];
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[navController setViewControllers:controllers];
```

If you paste just this to - `[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`, you'll see that it works immediately.